# How to block calls/SMS by contact name (might have multiple phone numbers)?

Tags: contacts, call-screening, sms-blocking, spam

I'm using Moto X. I used to blacklist spammers directly into the downloaded app or the built-in Android blocker.

The problem is that every time that I reset my phone to factory settings, I have to add all numbers again, one by one.

So I created a contact on Google called "SPAM", and inserted all spam numbers into it.

Is there a way to simply block the contact called "SPAM", instead of adding dozens of numbers again?

Comment: This is academic, really, when using Google Voice. Unfortunately, GV is not universally available.

Comment: @AlE. yes. unfortunately, not available in my country yet.

Comment: Lots and Lots apps are available for the same. Just a Play needed.

Comment: @See-Sharp i know. i have tried at least 20 apps. its really hard to find one that can block by contact name, not by number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mr. Number](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrnumber.blocker) added this feature to recent versions.

When you select a contact name to block, it adds **all** phone numbers related to that contact to the blacklist.

Answer (score 2):

From within the stock Android environment, you can at least force contacts to the voicemail. It is not possible to block SMS directly, at least not without root (to my knowledge).

I have a Nexus 4, so your options might differ from what I have.

If you go in the People app, you'll be able to find your SPAM contact. In the top-right corner, you'll have the ⋮ button (or the menu button on the device). There will be an option "All calls to voicemail". If you check this, all numbers within that contact will be sent to your voicemail and won't vibrate/alert you.

Comment: does not apply for kitkat (4.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [BlackList](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.baole.app.blacklist)?

> Blocking:
>
> - Block call/text/MMS messages for a blacklist (a list of numbers)
> - Block call/text/MMS messages for private numbers (no numbers, no caller id), numbers not in my contacts
> - Block call/text message for pre-/post-fix numbers
> - Exception list (don't block list) (PRO)
> - Text filters by plain text or regular expression, prefix-matches, postfix matches.

Comment: yes. does not block by contact name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Go SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms)? It can block by text filters

> - SMS blocker smartly block blacklist/keywords and filter spam messages

Comment: it works for sms, but not for contact names.